# Do cryptographic hash functions reach each possible values, i.e., are they surjective?

Tags: math, hash, cryptography

Take a commonly used binary hash function - for example, SHA-256. As the name implies, it outputs a 256 bit value.

Let *A* be the set of all possible 256 bit binary values. *A* is extremely large, but finite.

Let *B* be the set of all possible binary values. *B* is infinite.

Let *C* be the set of values obtained by running SHA-256 on every member of *B*. Obviously this can't be done in practice, but I'm guessing we can still do mathematical analysis of it.

**My Question:** By necessity, *C* ⊆ *A*. But does *C* = *A*?

EDIT: As was pointed out by some answers, this is wholly dependent on the has function in question. So, if you know the answer for any particular hash function, please say so!

Comment: A question for mathoverflow? But theoretically, I think `C=A`.

Comment: It certainly could apply there. But since hash functions are so important in programming, and since thats why I'm actually asking the question, I thought I'd ask it here.

Comment: I suggest you still cross-post this on mathoverflow (with a link in both directions).

Comment: Also look at [feistel ciphers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher), which can construct a random permutation (with fixed input size) from a cryptographic hash (with output half as long.)

Comment: I've asked for this question to be migrated to crypto.SE. I mentioned that I would not ask for migration again if rejected; I meant this to mean that I would not do this because I would assume that the migration of old questions that *have become* off topic are not considered for migration by the SE community / the ops.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658601/do-cryptographic-hash-functions-reach-each-possible-values-i-e-are-they-surje

Answer (score 42, accepted):

First, let's point out that SHA-256 does not accept all possible binary strings as input. As defined by [FIPS 180-3](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips180-3/fips180-3_final.pdf), SHA-256 accepts as input any sequence of bits of length lower than *2^64* bits (i.e. no more than 18446744073709551615 bits). This is very common; all hash functions are somehow limited in formal input length. One reason is that the notion of security is defined with regards to computational cost; there is a threshold about computational power that any attacker may muster. Inputs beyond a given length would require more than that maximum computational power to simply evaluate the function. In brief, cryptographers are very wary of infinites, because infinites tend to prevent security from being even defined, let alone quantified. So your input set *C* should be restricted to sequences up to *2^64-1* bits.

That being said, let's see what is known about hash function surjectivity.

Hash functions try to emulate a *random oracle*, a conceptual object which selects outputs at random under the only constraint that it "remembers" previous inputs and outputs, and, if given an already seen input, it returns the same output than previously. By definition, a random oracle can be proven surjective only by trying inputs and exhausting the output space. If the output has size *n* bits, then it is expected that about *2^(2n)* distinct inputs will be needed to exhaust the output space of size *2^n*. For *n = 256*, this means that hashing about *2^512* messages (e.g. all messages of 512 bits) ought to be enough (on average). SHA-256 accepts inputs very much longer than 512 bits (indeed, it accepts inputs up to 18446744073709551615 bits), so it seems *highly plausible* that SHA-256 is surjective.

**However**, it has not been proven that SHA-256 is surjective, and that is **expected**. As shown above, a surjectivity proof for a random oracle requires an awful lot of computing power, substantially more than mere attacks such as preimages (*2^n*) and collisions (*2^(n/2)*). Consequently, a good hash function "should not" allow a property such as surjectivity to be actually proven. It would be very suspicious: security of hash function stems from the intractability of their internal structure, and such an intractability should firmly oppose to any attempt at mathematical analysis.

As a consequence, surjectivity is not formally proven for any decent hash function, and not even for "broken" hash functions such as MD4. It is only "highly suspected" (a random oracle with inputs much longer than the output should be surjective).

Comment: Your proposition may or may not be true,  but your argument is,  at best, grossly oversimplified to the point of being incorrect,  and at worst completely bogus.   You are misapplying the random oracle model,  and since we can work with the internal structure of SHA-1,  there is the possibility of definitively proving surjectivity without attacking SHA-1 itself.    For example,  you can easily prove surjectivity of a modified SHA-1 with a parameterized IV.

Comment: Why would it take about 2^(2n) distinct inputs to exhaust the 2^n possible outputs? The coupon-collector problem says it takes an average of about k ln k attempts to collect one of each of k categories. If k=2^n, k ln k = ln 2 n 2^n, which is much smaller than 2^(2n).

Comment: Right, it wouldn't take 2^(2n) distinct inputs; as you pointed out it would be just 2^n * n * ln(2), which for n=256 is about 2^263.5 .... but seeing as how 2^263.5 << 2^512 <<< 2^(2^64), this observation only makes it a fortiori even more "highly suspected" that SHA-256 is surjective (barring some heretofore-undiscovered cryptographic structural flaw).

Answer (score 6):

Not necessarily. The pigeonhole principle states that once one more hash beyond the size of A has been generated that there is a probability of collision of 1, but it does *not* state that every single element of A has been generated.

Comment: +1. The pigeonhole principle is about injectivity (i.e. impossibility thereof).

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on the hash function. If you use this valid hash function:

```
Int256 Hash (string input) {
    return 0;
}
```

then it is obvious that C != A. So the "for example, SHA256" is a pretty important note to consider.

To answer your actual question: I believe so, but I'm just guessing. Wikipedia does not provide any meaningful info on this.

Comment: Your hash function is certainly not a cryptographic one :-)

Comment: Your function does not qualify as a valid hash function, because you can trivially construct its inverse function, for example `string InverseHash(Int256 hash) { return hash == 0 ? "asdf" : null; }`

Comment: @jlh The given function is a valid hash function. It is not a useful cryptographic hash function, tho.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. That would depend on the hash function.

It would probably be ideal if the hash function was [surjective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective), but there are things that're usually more important, such as a low likelihood of collisions.

Answer (score 0):

It is not always the case. However, quality required for an hash algorithm are:

- Cardinality of B
- Repartition of hashes in B (every value in B must have the same probability to be a hash)