# How many values can hashlib.sha256(hashlib.sha256(str(x).encode()).digest()).hexdigest() have?

Tags: python, sha256

I am aware that for any `x`, 
`int(hashlib.sha256(str(x).encode()).hexdigest(), 16)` has 2**256 possible values. 
How many possible values does the following have then?

```
int(hashlib.sha256(hashlib.sha256(str().encode()).digest()).hexdigest(), 16)
```

I assume it has 2**256 possible values as it is a SHA-256 hash anyway.

Comment: A SHA-256 hash always has a fixed output length, so its *maximum* value is well defined, whether expressed as binary value or hex or `int`. Are you asking whether the fact that you're hashing a hash changes anything about the possible *distribution* of values? Ideally it wouldn't.

Comment: The exact answer is a number between 1 and 2\**256. I don't know the exact answer, but I think it will be very close to 2\**256.

Comment: "I am aware that [hash function here] has `2**256` possible values." How do you know that? That `2**256` is an upper bound is obvious. But how do you know that every value is realizable? In fact this is an open problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658601/do-cryptographic-hash-functions-reach-each-possible-value-e-g-are-they-surject AFAIK

Comment: Sorry I am unfamiliar to this topic and I might have misstated based on my shallow understanding. Yes I was asking whether the fact that hashing a hash changes the possible distribution.

Comment: Assuming the hash is perfect, and can produce all possible 2\*\*256 values from your string, and that it also returns a unique value for all possible 2\*\*256 inputs, i.e. there’s no collision within the first 2\*\*256 possible inputs, then the answer is yes, it’ll output 2\*\*256 possible values. Basically you’re asking for the possibility of collisions of SHA-256.